# How do I change "is made of" into an active voice?

Tags: passive-voice, active-vs-passive

How do I change the sentence "this candle is made of natural soy wax" into an active voice? Also, can someone please explain why Grammarly considers "is made of" a passive voice misuse?

Comment: Just throw out "made of". ***This candle is natural soy wax***. Or perhaps more idiomatically in most contexts, ***This is a  natural soy wax candle***. But *never* believe Grammarly if it conflicts with other "authoritative" sources.

Comment: Grammarly is simply wrong here. "is made of" is not passive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with

> This candle is made of/from natural soy wax.

To make it in the active voice, you might use

> consists of

or less precisely/accurately

> has / contains

<sup>First ask yourself why you want to change the sentence. However advanced Grammarly is, it's still far from giving sensible hints all the time.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you regard "X is made of Y" as passive, by analogy with "built from" or "fashioned with", you can make it active by supplying an actor as subject and making "it" the object:

They made it of plastic.
Someone made it of bubble gum.

Comment: ...but please don't. This sounds awkward and forced, especially in that season of *How It's Made* I watched once where they bent over backwards to avoid any hint of the passive voice, and it just sounded **bad.**